# If browser sends requests to https:// url, does it mean that requests are encrypted automatically?

Tags: https, web-applications

I need to ensure that communication between browser and server is secure. If browser sends requests to `https://` address, is it sufficient to rely that communication is encrypted, or additional configuration and checks should be done?

Comment: You can be sure that communication is encrypted unless client device (smartphone or PC) has some root CA pre-installed by someone - Look at [Kazakhstan government is now intercepting all HTTPS traffic](https://www.zdnet.com/article/kazakhstan-government-is-now-intercepting-all-https-traffic/)